# How to get mock telephonymanager service android

Tags: android, mockito

Actually i want to write some mock unit tests for telephony manger , i am using mockito framework to mock telephony service. I am returning particular operator name based on my configurations it is not working.

```
      Context mockContext = mock(Context.class);
                TelephonyManager mockTelephonyManager = mock(TelephonyManager.class);
                when(mockContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).thenReturn(mockTelephonyManager);
             when(mockTelephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName()).thenReturn("SomeNetwork");
assertTrue("SomeNetwork",some.getNetworkOperatorName());
    // callling method
    SomeClass some = new SomeClass();
    some.getNetworkOperatorName();
    class SomeClass{

    public String getNetworkOperatorName(){
     TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            return telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();

    }

    }
```

Comment: Could you explain "it is not working" in more details. It's not clear what do you expect and what is the actual behavior :)

Comment: not receiving a proper value whatever sending  when(mockTelephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName()).thenReturn("SomeNetwork");

Comment: Please, show how the `mockTelephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName()` is called from your test

Comment: i am calling telephonymanager.getNetworkOperatorName() in some method

Comment: It is not clear what it the full workflow from mocking to calling the method on the mock. Please, create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is possible to reproduce and help you.

Comment: I edited my question please find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see here is that `mockContext` dos not get injected to `SomeClass` instance.
You can either do it using constructor injection:

```
SomeClass(Context context) {
  this.context = contest;
}
```

and in the test just initialize it like this:

```
SomeClass some = new SomeClass(mockContext);
```

Or you can use mockito annotations to create and inject mocks:

```
@Mock
private Context mockContext;

@InjectMocks
private SomeClass someClass;

@Test
public void test() {
  TelephonyManager mockTelephonyManager = mock(TelephonyManager.class);
  when(mockContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).thenReturn(mockTelephonyManager);
  when(mockTelephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName()).thenReturn("SomeNetwork");
  assertTrue("SomeNetwork",someClass.getNetworkOperatorName());
}
```

In this case, make sure to annotate your test class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or to call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` method.

Either of this should work.

Comment: SomeClass not require context in constructor , it is getting from dagger injection

Comment: Then you can use injection using mockito annotations. The issue is that mockito does not know about dagger injection. It knows only about java classes, and the mocked dependency must be injected into `SomeClass` somehow. Mockito annotations can help you with this